# update_post_meta for Custom Post Type in Wordpress doesn't work

Tags: wordpress

but I'm trying to create a Custom Post Type, add a Meta Box and save the Custom Filed in it. Now when i click save the value of my input text doesn't save, it remain empty.

Here is my code (my first attempt), hope someone may help me, thanks :)

```
<?php

//DEFINISCO IL CUSTOM POST TYPE TETTI
add_action( 'init', 'tetti_post_type' );
function tetti_post_type() {

$labels_tetti = array (
    'name' => __('Tetti'),
    'singular_name' => __('Tetto'),
    'add_new' => __('Aggiungi Tetto'),
    'add_new_item' => __('Aggiungi Nuovo Tetto'),
    'view_item' => __('Vedi Tetto')
    );

$args_tetti = array (
    'labels' => $labels_tetti,
    'public' => true,
    'publicly_querable' => true,
    'show_ui' => true,
    'rewrite' =>true,
    'menu_position' => 5
    );

register_post_type ('tetti', $args_tetti);
}
//AGGANCIO I CAMPI PRESONALIZZATI AL CUSTOM POST TYPE TETTI
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'custom_field_tetti' );

function custom_field_tetti(){
add_meta_box('specifiche_tetti_meta', 'Specifiche Tetti', 'specifiche_tetti', 'tetti', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function specifiche_tetti(){
global $post;
$custom_seriale = get_post_custom($post->ID);
$tetti_seriale = $custom_seriale['tetti_seriale'][0]; ?>
<label>Seriale:</label>
<input type="text" id="tetti_seriale" name="tetti_seriale" value="<?php echo $tetti_seriale; ?>"/>

<?php }

//SALVO I CAMPI PRESONALIZZATI DEL CUSTOM POST TYPE TETTI
add_action('save_post', 'save_specifiche_tetti');
global $post;
function save_specifiche_tetti(){
update_post_meta($post->ID, 'tetti_seriale', $_POST['tetti_seriale']);
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have `'global $post;'` outside of the `save_specifiche_tetti` function, so your `update_post_meta` has no access to the `ID`